# Getting unwanted commas after div

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, html-table

`

Here's the code written in TypeScript.

This is code to build HTML table which display items from Nested objects. This code works fine but just there is an issue in printing like it should only create table with rows but it is also printing some coma's which are not even part of any line which is executed

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
  
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular';
  data = {
    id: '0001',
    type: 'donut',
    name: 'Cake',
    ppu: 0.55,
    batters: {
      batter: [{
          id: '1001',
          type: 'Regular'
        },
        {
          id: '1002',
          type: 'Chocolate'
        },
        {
          id: '1003',
          type: 'Blueberry'
        },
        {
          id: '1004',
          type: "Devil's Food"
        }
      ]
    },
    topping: [{
        id: '5001',
        type: 'None'
      },
      {
        id: '5002',
        type: 'Glazed'
      },
      {
        id: '5005',
        type: 'Sugar'
      },
      {
        id: '5007',
        type: 'Powdered Sugar'
      },
      {
        id: '5006',
        type: 'Chocolate with Sprinkles'
      },
      {
        id: '5003',
        type: 'Chocolate'
      },
      {
        id: '5004',
        type: 'Maple'
      }
    ]
  };

  //Function which build HTML Table which get's dynamic values.

  htmlStr = (data, wrapperClassName, tableClassName = 'table table-sm') => {
    return `
    <div class=${tableClassName}>
      <table className=${tableClassName}>

        <tbody>

          ${Object.keys(data).map( (k) => `
          <tr>
            ${(!Array.isArray(data) && `
            <td>${k.replace(/_/g, ' ')}</td>`) || ''} ${ data[k] && typeof data[k] === 'object' ? `
            <td>
              ${this.htmlStr(data[k], wrapperClassName, tableClassName)}
            </td>` : `
            <td>
              <span>${data[k] || ''}</span>
            </td>` }
          </tr>` )}
        </tbody>

      </table>

    </div>`;
  };
}
```

Comment: You should join your array by an empty string if you don't want commas `Object.keys(data).map(...).join("")`. When JS automatically converts your array to a string, it automatically joins it with a `,`

Comment: @Muhammad, curiosity: is there any reason to create the table in this way (using a variable) and not simply iterating in the .html using *ngFor?

Comment: @eliseo Not any specific reason I was actually converting a react library code in to ts and it's working fine.

Comment: But it's not a good reason. In Angular there is no "render" function. Components have a template or templateurl property that does this. You get into trouble early when you try to signal events and you lose all projection potentialities, the power of directives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code the snippet `Object.keys(data).map(.....)` converts it to array. Now when you put this array in string literal JavaScript will try to convert it to a string so it will call `.toString()` on it which joins all the elements of array using `,` by default.

instead do this `Object.keys(data).map(....).join("")` this will join array with empty string